# macOS screencapture only taking images of Desktop

Tags: applescript, screen-capture

I've created an AppleScript shortcut to take a screenshot. However, the resulting screenshot only displays the Desktop, even if other apps are in focus. Here is my AppleScript snippet:

```
do shell script "screencapture -dxi /private/tmp/test.png"
```

I've also compiled with `osacompile` and launched the app through the Finder, which same results. I've checked file directory and permissions (plus System Preferences) and everything checks out.

If I were to execute this command from the Terminal, then it runs as expected. My guess is that by running the app by double-clicking it in the Finder then a different user is used and results in inadequate permissions.

Comment: According to https://ss64.com/osx/screencapture.html the `-i` parameter puts it in interactive mode, so it is waiting for a window or marquee selection. Have you tried it without, or are you actually generating the user input to specify your interactive selection?

Comment: Tested in a script. `-i` gives me the crosshairs, which I can swap to 'window' with spacebar. Both methods work fine.  I used ~/Desktop & gave Script editor full disk perms [otherwise it errors]. Without `-i` it just screenshots the entire primary display, no interaction required.

Comment: @Tetsujin thanks for the help! The solution was a permissions correction in System Preferences after all.. Turns out that providing screen capture permissions to the osacompile output in my /Applications directory is not enough. There was another generated applet which needed permissions as well. Hope this helps someone in the future!

Comment: For completeness here is the osacompile line I used to derive my app.. `osacompile -o /Applications/<APP NAME>.app <PATH TO APPLESCRIPT>/screencapture.scpt`